# Ionic 3 - App not working in background

Tags: ionic3, ionic-native

I have created one demo of recording audio in the background mode using "@ionic-native/background-mode". App is working fine in background when user clicks home button directly. But when user clicks the back button and exits the app it does not work in background.

**Code:**

```
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {
     constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,private backgroundMode:BackgroundMode) {
     }
     ionViewDidLoad() {
          this.backgroundMode.enable();
     }
}
```

Have i made any mistake or i forgot something in code? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: check with `isEnabled()`. if **true** or **false**

Comment: i already have checked, Not working! @codeMonkey